# What is the benefit of combining a form with php processing script in a single page using isset

Tags: php, html

I would like to know the benefits of using a single page with both the PHP processing script and the HTML form using `isset()` as opposed to simply using form action with method POST on one page to call a separate page for processing the submitted form contents.

It seems `isset()` can cause problems with null values.

Can someone clarify the benefits particularly if there are any security benefits or issues between calling a PHP processing page from an HTML form page and using a single page with PHP processing, HTML form and `isset()` to determine whether the form is displayed or the contents processed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no benefits or drawbacks security-wise.

Technically it's always **two** calls to the server, one to load the form and one to process it, no matter how many files you have. So it's just the way to organize your files, nothing more.

No, `isset()` cannot cause problems with null values, as a regular HTML form cannot send values of any type other than **string** - so there would be not a single null value to deal with.

What is very important to understand: anything could be faked.

- the form could be read or could be not
- The handler could be called by a browser from the form page, or could be called by a bot with the form fields completely forged. There is no way to tell one call from another.
- the form could be read, but the data could be tampered with, fields removed or renamed or edited
- some fiend types (notably checkboxes) are not sent from the form if not selected

So you should treat your handler script as a self-sufficient application that doesn't trust anything sent from the client side. And, among other things, you should always check whether the form has been set, no matter if it's a single script or two separate ones.

Besides, there is no use for `isset()` if you have the form and the processing code on a single page as opposed to having two pages. `isset()` is just irrelevant to that. Once you need it, you need it for both implementations.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation.  I thought isset() was used to determine if the submit button had been clicked and data sent.  I thought it was used to determine whether the form was displayed or the processing executed.  Can I ask then when you need isset() in particular and how you would use the form and php code on the same page and determine if php was to be executed or the form displayed - or is this a separate question, in any case - thanks again

Comment: Just use it to determine if php was to be executed or the form displayed, it's a perfectly valid use case. My point was that you need the same condition on the separate script as well, as not to run the processing if the handler was called directly.

Comment: good point, perfectly clear now, thanks again - I also accepted your answer :-)